# showing loading using jquery ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I upgrade my DOM ajax to jquery ajax in passing a value using post, the problem now is the loading image, i tried to follow some of the sample here but to no success. here's my code:

```
function passLetter(str)
    {       
        $('#loadingImage').attr('style','display:');
        // $('#retail_group').html('<img src="/admin/images/ajax-loader.gif" style="text-align:center;">');
                    //$('#loadingImage').show();                                
        $.ajax({
        url: "getRetailGroup.php",
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        data:  {"letter": str},
        success: function(data){
                $("#retail_group").html(data);
                //$('#loadingImage').hide();
            }
        });
        getletter = str;
    }
```

for the div:

```
<div id="retail_group">
<div id="loadingImage" style = "display:none">
<img src="/admin/images/ajax-loader.gif" style="text-align:center;" alt = "Loader" title = "Loader">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: has anything helped you? or have abandon this question?

Comment: none has helped me so far. no i haven't abandon this question and i am still open for ideas.

Comment: ok well you need to tell us what's not working. Did you try the answers given?

Comment: @Eonasdan all of them actually. it works fine using the old DOM ajax but then i wanted to make it simplier.

Comment: what? that doesn't even make sense. Look at my answer, you need to check to make sure that the path is right to the image and than change your jquery. If you don't understand the answers or we don't understand your question you need to update your question so we can help

Comment: @Eonasdan the image path is correct, my guess is that the script cant access the id inside the retail_group div. since when i transferred the loadingimage outside retaul_group div it somehow works.

Comment: I see what you did now. I'm surprise the rest missed this too. I've updated my answer. Which is funny since it's in your commented out code

Comment: @Eonasdan what did you change in your answer?

Comment: sorry posted the comment before I changed my answer, check now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('#loadingImage').show();
```

**OR**

```
 $('#loadingImage').css('display','block');
```

I think your `#loadingImage` div has already CSS `display: none`.

Comment: tried that with .show and .hide but still nothing. 
also tried:
$('#retail_group').html('<img src="/admin/images/ajax-loader.gif" style="text-align:center;">');

but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
$('#loadingImage').attr('style','display:');
```

try:

```
$('#loadingImage').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change to 
    `$('#loadingImage').css('display','block');`
or even simpler: 
    `$('#loadingImage').show();`

Answer (score 0):

For one, you should be using jquery's `show()` and `hide()` functions instead.

```
$('#loadingImage').show();
```

secondly make sure that you can in fact get to the image based on your image path in the browser

```
http://site.com/admin/images/ajax-loader.gif
```

if you use jquery's show/hide then you need to remove

```
style = "display:none">
```

Put `$('#loadingImage').hide();` in your document ready block

Oh, and if you want to set css to an element with jquery it should be like this

```
$('#loadingImage').css("display","block");
```

**Edit**

Your real problem is that you are **replacing** `retail_group`'s html with the ajax result. When you do that the next time the function is called there is no more `loadingImage` div to show

```
$("#retail_group").html(data);
```

You need to to change your function like this:

```
function passLetter(str)
    {       
     $('#retail_group').html('<img src="/admin/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>');                       
        $.ajax({
        url: "getRetailGroup.php",
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        data:  {"letter": str},
        success: function(data){
                $("#retail_group").html(data);
            }
        });
        getletter = str;
    }
```

now each time the function is called the inside of `retail_group` will be the image until the ajax has completed **successfully**

Comment: actually that's what i did before and its still not working. i tried removing .html(data) and the loading appears. i guess its too fast that it skips the first .html

Comment: look at the [php sleep function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php). add that to your `getRetailGroup.php` for testing purposes. see if that image displays then

Comment: still nothing. it seems it is ignoring the first .html and proceeds directly and waits for the success to appear

Comment: check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BeX2J/) there has to be something else wrong. comment out the `$("#retail_group").html(data);` part and make sure the image shows